# i want to make element one under the other in css

Tags: html, css

So I want to make the form element and the button of className "new-count" one under the other but I failed to do so this is my HTML code :

```
<div className="register">
           <h1>Private</h1>
           <div className="login" >
               
               <form className="form" >
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
               <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
               <button type="submit" >Login</button>
              
               </form>
               <button className="new-count"> Create account</button>
           
           </div>
       </div>

the CSS code:
.login {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 top: 25%;
 left: 200%;
 justify-content: center;
 max-width: 10hv;
height: 300px;
padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 justify-content: center;
}
.login.form {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80%; 

   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   align-items: center;
}
.login.form input{

 position: relative;
 width: 80%;
 height: 20%;
 flex-direction: column;
 
 justify-content: center;

 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: .8em;
 background: #efefef;
 border: 3px solid #333;
}
button {

 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #075a23;
 color: #fff;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.new-count {

 width: 100%;
 height: 15px;
 
}
```

so I want to make my page like the register page facebook :
[image] ====> to this [image]

Comment: ```.login.form {display: inline-block;}``` targets an element that has _both_ ```login``` and ```form``` classes. Also, why use ```display:inline-block``` at all? Kick it, should work fine then.

Comment: Another comment. You wouldn't use ```className=""``` in HTML. You would use className in javascript, for html elements you need ```class="myClass"```

Comment: i kick it but it not work

Comment: i work with react my friend that's why i use className

Comment: Might be useful to flag your post with "react" if you are using react

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine on codepen. It may something from your browser/resolution.

Try this code snippet:

```css
.login {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 top: 25%;
 left: 200%;
 justify-content: center;
 max-width: 10hv;
height: 300px;
padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 justify-content: center;
}
.login.form {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80%; 

   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   align-items: center;
}
.login.form input{

 position: relative;
 width: 80%;
 height: 20%;
 flex-direction: column;
 
 justify-content: center;

 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: .8em;
 background: #efefef;
 border: 3px solid #333;
}
button {

 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #075a23;
 color: #fff;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.new-count {

 width: 100%;
 height: 15px;
 
}
```

```html
<div className="register">
           <h1>Private</h1>
           <div className="login" >
               
               <form className="form" >
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
               <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
               <button type="submit" >Login</button>
              
               </form>
               <button className="new-count"> Create account</button>
           
           </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: i reinitialize my app and it didin't work like i want

Comment: Try running it without local host